# Re-render component with componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a .jsx with a parent class and a child, in the parent i initialize the api and stock the json content in a state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        all: '',
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadApi();
}

loadApi(){
    this.setState({ all: myApiGet('https://********') });
}
```

After that i need to get the "url" of the differents pics for show them on the site. But there is the problem, I get the api json when i load the page and i don't success to re-load the function.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.apiGetProductPicture(nextProps.categorie);
}

apiGetProductPicture = (i) => () => {
        // TODO do something with the data
    var stock = this.props.all
        .then(stock => this.setState({ pictures: stock.content.categories[i].background }))

        .catch(error => console.log('home2', error));
}
```

I try a lot of possibility and check the net but the solution doesn't work for me (or i just doesn't understand them ...)

Thanks for your time :/

Full component:

```
class ProductItem extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pictures: '',
        name: '',
        price: '',
        json: '',
    };
    //this.apiGetProductPicture = this.apiGetProductPicture.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.apiGetProductPicture(nextProps.categorie);
}

apiGetProductPicture = (i) => () => {
        // TODO do something with the data
    var stock = this.props.all
        .then(stock => this.setState({ pictures: stock.content.categories[i].background }))

        .catch(error => console.log('home2', error));
}


render() {
    return (
             ......
           )
          }
}
```

Error message:

The above error occurred in the  component:
    in ProductItem (created by Home2)
    in div (created by Home2)
    in div (created by Home2)
    in div (created by Home2)
    in div (created by Home2)
    in main (created by Home2)
    in Home2

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
You can learn more about error boundaries at https:// fb.me/react-error-boundaries.
react-dom.development.js:9312:5
ReferenceError: props is not defined

Comment: Could you post the entire component that you've shown us the `componentWillReceiveProps` for?

Comment: Sure, i will post it in edit

Comment: Ask me if you need other informations :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i see some changes to be made
in your parent component your setting this.state.all to be a promise (the promise returned from your api call)

let's change that to be the actual json from your api call

Parent component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        all: '',
    };

    this.loadApi = this.loadApi.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadApi();
}

loadApi() {
    myApiGet('https://********')
        .then(all => this.setState({ all }));
}
```

Child Component:

```
class ProductItem extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pictures: '',
            name: '',
            price: '',
            json: '',
        };
        this.apiGetProductPicture = this.apiGetProductPicture.bind(this);
    }

    ComponetDidMount() {
         apiGetProductPicture(this.props.categorie);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.categorie !== this.props.categorie)
        {
            this.apiGetProductPicture(nextProps.categorie);
        }
    }

    apiGetProductPicture(categorie) {
        // TODO do something with the data
        if (!this.props.all) return;
        var categories = (((this.props.all || {}).stock || {}).content || {}).categories;

        if (categories.indexOf(categorie) > -1)
        {
            this.setState({ pictures: categories[categorie].background }));
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
             ......
        );
    }
}
```

> Thanks for your time :/

no worries :)

Comment: can you edit the address into ***** ? :') i look that now !

Comment: No :/ i have this message in console, i post it in first message for be more clear.

Comment: 2 questions: "!==" it write correctly or it's "!=" ?  And this line:   if (categories.indexOf(categorie) > -1) .  What is indexOf ?

Comment: "!==" and "!=" are both correct but different, "!=" has a coercive nature like ("0" != 0) would actually yield false to "!=" they are the same, but ("0" !== 0) would yield true (since they are different), similar to "==" "==="

Comment: Array.prototype.indexOf(), basically if ("is category in categories")

Comment: if (nextProps.categorie !== props.categorie) should be if (nextProps.categorie !== this.props.categorie)

Comment: I think i localize the problem, in "componentWillReceiveProps, if i let like you write (exept props.categorie => this.props.categorie) nothing happen but page load, if i erase the if, page crash.

Comment: MAy be an itteration too hight im not sure

Comment: I would hope “if (nextProps.categorie !== this.props.categorie)” should work

Comment: If i let this if, nothing bad happen  but img are not loaded, if i erase the if, the page crash. He never enter in the function :/

Comment: I have an idea, i changed the Child Component to add. ComponetDidMount

Comment: An other change added safe guards on apiGetProductPicture

Comment: With this configuration (i removed the "stock" dont exist, it was a variable i made) the page load but no pictures. So i think the function are never used.

Comment: I put console.log test, and the only display is just after   "   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {   "

Comment: he never enter in the if, and never in the componentDidMount

Comment: Maybe add a console.count(“getProductPicture”) and see if it fires up, also what do you do with this.state.pictures ? In the code you showed it’s only being set, not used

Comment: <li>
                                    <a data-image={this.state.pictures} href="#"><img src="/images/colorswatch/color-green.png" alt="Green" /></a>
                                </li>

Comment: 5 ! and after only the loadApi function show console log !

Comment: I put it in the constructor and he count 5. Only after the console.log of the myApiGet appear, its strange no?

Comment: Mmm “data-image” that’s just setting the dataset of the <a/> why not set a <img src={this.state.pictures} />

Comment: i don't know this part, like i said i help for a project but this was a part of a theme if i don't say mistakes. So somethings can be strange, that was where the other url pic was.

Comment: but if you want know, i already success to put the url of our bdd in this place and see the pictures, but fir a strange reason that was 4times on 5 an error so i must clean code and try find other way :/

Comment: Ok now he enter in willreceive and have the good value, so the problem is in apiGetProductPicture, continue my test (Thanks so much for your time you are very nice :/ )

Comment: Possible that all (parent) dont have value ? console log dont show value

Comment: I try put my old function, when i do that he enter in will receive 4 times. The problem il "all" when i console log this.props.all site crash.

Comment: Sorry i don’t think i can help you further without lookig a the actual code, and testing and such, sorry, but i would add that <img src={this.state.pictures} /> to see what happens, hope you eork it out

Comment: Thanks so much :) I will continue to try haha ! Let's go ;D (no :p)

Answer (score 0):

i se you posted "Lost in the javascriptception"
this and other questions have provided me with enough info to solve your problem, sorry the stackoverflow community was so mean to you, but not all of us are like that.

I would recommend in the future you post more info on your questions, like full code (except sensible stuff), not just parts, the codesanbox was the thing that let me test code and see where the problem was.

Also i f*** up on some of the previous answer, but to be fair i had very limited info to go along with, and most people answering won't test the code for tipos or stuff

version One

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class ProductItem extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pictures: '',
      name: '',
      price: '',
      json: '',
    };

    this.apiGetProductPicture = this.apiGetProductPicture.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.apiGetProductPicture(this.props.categorie);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.apiGetProductPicture(nextProps.categorie);
  }

  apiGetProductPicture(categorie) {
    // TODO do something with the data
    var categories = this.props.send;
    categorie = parseInt(categorie, 10);

    if (categorie < categories.length) {
      console.log(categories[categorie].background);
      this.setState({ pictures: categories[categorie].background });
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
        <img src={this.state.pictures} />
      </div>
        );
  }
}


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      all: "",
      categories: []
    };
    this.loadAPI = this.loadAPI.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAPI();
  }

  loadAPI() {

    var test = fetch("https:*******")
      .then(test => test.json())
      .then(testJson => {
        //  alert(testJson.content.categories[0].description)
        var obs = testJson.content.categories.slice();

        // alert(testJson);
        this.setState({ categories: obs });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
        <h1>Products</h1>
        {this.state.categories.map( (value, i) => {
          return <ProductItem
                key={value.uid}
                send={this.state.categories}
                name={value.description}
                categorie={i} />
        })}
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

My recommended Version

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class ProductItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
        <img src={this.props.picture} />
      </div>
        );
  }
}


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      all: "",
      categories: []
    };
    this.loadAPI = this.loadAPI.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAPI();
  }

  loadAPI() {

    var test = fetch("https:*****")
      .then(test => test.json())
      .then(testJson => {
        //  alert(testJson.content.categories[0].description)
        var obs = testJson.content.categories.slice();

        // alert(testJson);
        this.setState({ categories: obs });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
        <h1>Products</h1>
        {this.state.categories.map( (value, i) => {
          return <ProductItem
                key={value.uid}
                picture={value.background}
                name={value.description}
                categorie={i} />
        })}
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope this helps you out, don't be so hard on yourself, you know practice makes perfect, also would recommend you follow [the react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), to see what react is about, i can seam super hard and weird because it maybe a completely different programming model (it was for me), but when it click it's really cool

Comment: I success to find a way with your help, again i give to you the biggest thanks possible, seriously you help me to see my code with an other eyes ! You are a good teacher :D !!!